# Requesting multipart image upload along with other request attributes in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm new to android and I need to update my profile in my app. For this purpose, I need to upload image on server using multipart with some other fields like name, city, mobile, email, etc in a single request. Can anyone help me for making a POST request using Retrofit 2.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Multipart
@POST(/update_profile)

Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name, @RequestBody email, @RequestBody mobile);
```

Is this right or wrong?

How can I define the type of other fields, and for this, do I have to add different fields separately or can I make a model class for this like other normal requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can send other attributes along with multipart image

@Multipart
@POST("imageupload")
Call uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart, @Part String name);

Comment: sansesh for every field we have to mention seppratly with @part annotation?

Comment: Yes if your variable name is different than your method Param name you can use something like this @Part("imageName") String name